# How to keep radio button checked when selecting a disabled one in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following problem in IE(9,10,11): I have a group of radio buttons and some of them must be disabled, but still be submitted with the form. So I figured a way to do this using the following functions:

```
var doNothing = function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
}
var disableRadio = function($elem){
    $elem.bind('click.radiostate', doNothing);
    $elem.addClass('disabledRadioClass');
}
```

instead of adding `disabled` attribute, and styling the corresponding buttons with css: `opacity:.5;` in order to be displayed like disabled. The problem is, when I select the 'disabled' radio button in IE, the selected radio button becomes unchecked - even though it still has its `checked` attribute set to checked! Here is what I mean:

Before clicking the 'disabled' radio (Radio 2):

[image]

and after:

[image]

no selected radio whatsoever. When submitting the form and refreshing the page though, Radio 3 is selected again.

**What I want:** When clicking on the 'custom-made' disabled button, the selected button (e.g. Radio 3 in this case) should stay as it is (like in Chrome), so at least one of the radio buttons stays checked.

Comment: I tried it in IE11. Your code should work properly. See here - https://jsbin.com/yagirusima/edit?html,output

Comment: The example you're including gets the disabled one selected. This is not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this instead:

```
    var disableRadio = function($elem){
    /**
     * We need this in case of clicking on a disabled radio button: must know 
     * the previously checked radio button, so the selection stays as is and
     * does not disappear or move to the disabled one.
     * @type element
     */
    var $previouslySelectedRadioButton = $("input[name='"+$elem.attr("name")+"']:checked");
    /* Mouseup is executed before click, so by doing this we can get the 
     * previously checked radio before the disabled one gets the 
     * checked PROPERTY set to true. */
    $elem.bind('mouseup.radiostate', function(event){
        $previouslySelectedRadioButton = $("input[name='"+$(event.target).attr("name")+"']:checked");
    });
    //on click we return checked property to the previously selected radio
    $elem.bind('click.radiostate', function(){
        $previouslySelectedRadioButton.prop("checked", true);
        return false;
    });
    $elem.addClass('disabledRadioClass');
};
```

@Miguel Cabrera gave me an idea.

Answer (score 1):

add an event listener to the radiobutton

```js
var currentRadio = 'r2'
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('radio')
var len = els.length;

while(len--){
  els[len].addEventListener('click',function(ev){
    if(ev.currentTarget.id == 'r1'){
      document.getElementById(currentRadio).checked = true;
    } else {
      currentRadio = ev.currentTarget.id
    }
    
  })
}
document
.querySelector('#r1')
.style.opacity = .5
```

```html
<form>
<input class="radio" id="r1" name="name" value="radio1" type="radio">
<input class="radio" id="r2" name="name" value="radio2" type="radio">
<input class="radio" id="r3" name="name" value="radio3" type="radio">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding disabled attribute to radio buttons just hide them and add dummy disabled radio buttons at their places and do vice versa when you want them enable again.

Comment: This is not applicable because the radio buttons are rendered through a list, and I cannot work on each of them separately. It requires too much refactoring and js code.